# What is the "ALBM" folder for?

Tags: olympus, filesystems

I have an Olympus EM-10 III. When I put the SD card in my computer, there is a folder titled `ALBM` (along with the normal `DCIM` folder containing photos). Within it, there is a folder called `ALB67ZZ8.BIN`. When unzipped it with Archive Utility (the default Mac unzipper), it makes a file called `ALB67ZZ8.BIN.cpgz`. When that is opened, it makes a folder called `ALB67ZZ8.BIN 2.cpgz`, apparently duplicating itself. What is this file for? How can I open it?

Comment: My money on some thumbnails collection.

Comment: The gz part of the extension seems to indicate gzip, another compressed format. The second file was likely produced after decompression. Try opening it to see if what's inside is recognizable.

Comment: "bin" is rather generic, just because the extension is associated, it doesn't mean that the software can actually read the file. The behaviour you describe also happens when the file you are trying to extract isn't actually a compressed file (it spits a copy of the file with the cpgz extension). I could not find any info about this on google tho :(

Comment: More info on cpgz: https://wetransfer.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005480583-Can-t-unzip-transfer-on-Mac-and-instead-it-creates-cpgz-file

Comment: Thank you for asking this question. The first entry in search results was "Air-launched ballistic missile" and I got worried for a moment.

Answer (score 5):

This is a fantastic question!

I copied the file off my E-M10 III (same filename incidentally, so not based on serial) and opened it in HxD. This is what the beginning looks like:

```
Offset(h) 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F  Decoded text
00000000  30 30 30 33 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  0003............
00000010  00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
00000020  03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00  ................
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
00000040  00 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
00000050  07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 00  ................
00000060  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
00000070  00 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
00000080  0B 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0C 00 00 00  ................
00000090  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0D 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
000000A0  00 00 00 00 0E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
000000B0  0F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00  ................
000000C0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 11 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
000000D0  00 00 00 00 12 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
000000E0  13 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 14 00 00 00  ................
000000F0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 15 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
```

This is the first portion of the file. The first column shows the position in the file in hexadecimal. The next sixteen columns show the value of each byte in hexadecimal. Finally, the far right shows the equivalent text.

Clearly, not much is stored in the beginning of the file. I had a quick look through the rest of the file, but it appears to be empty except the beginning and the end.

---

My next guess is that ALBM is a shortened version of 'album'. While the camera doesn't have a feature for saving photos to different albums, it does include a 'My Clips' feature. It is used for basic video editing in camera - it basically allows joining short video clips (up to 16 seconds each) and photos together, as well as adding artistic effects, transitions and background music. Basically for making a cheesy holiday powerpoint in-camera.

While this is just a guess, I went ahead and added some photos to a new clip, and downloaded the file off the camera again. The file had changed.

```
Offset(h) 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F  Decoded text

000004A0  63 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 50 36 31 37  c...........P617
000004B0  31 31 34 35 2E 4A 50 47 64 00 02 00 DA 70 58 00  1145.JPGd...ÚpX.
000004C0  2F B5 0C 00 00 00 01 00 50 36 31 37 31 31 34 36  /µ......P6171146
000004D0  2E 4A 50 47 64 00 02 00 29 7A 54 00 8E B7 0C 00  .JPGd...)zT.Ž·..
000004E0  00 00 01 00 50 36 31 37 31 31 34 38 2E 4A 50 47  ....P6171148.JPG
000004F0  64 00 02 00 2F BB 53 00 3D BC 0C 00 00 00 01 00  d.../»S.=¼......
00000500  50 36 31 37 31 31 34 39 2E 4A 50 47 64 00 02 00  P6171149.JPGd...
00000510  4B 79 50 00 87 BE 0C 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00  KyP.‡¾..........
```

This is a different section of the file to the one before, but this was not present previously.

The filenames of the images I added to the My Clip appear. The strange characters between them are likely other metadata, potentially when I added them or duration. I haven't used the My Clips feature so I'm not sure what attributes each section has.

It doesn't appear to contain the filenames of images that are marked as needing to be shared or being protected.

Comment: Nice answer. For those of use not using the EM10, could you give a brief idea of what "My Clips" is in order to round off this answer please.

Comment: Thank you @dmkonlinux! I've done this now (in the paragraph right after the delimiter). I don't think many people use this feature and I wouldn't be surprised if it were dropped from the E-M10 IV.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, *why* do you want to open this file? Are you missing some photos/videos/data and suspect they are held within this file? Surely not. The `.bin` extension would indicate to me that this is a [binary file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file) – probably some kind of "catalogue" file, encoded in some proprietary way by Olympus, that the camera uses for organising files or storing quick-view previews or something. I would suggest *leave well enough alone*.

Secondly, the file is not duplicating itself in some autonomous way. These additional files you are seeing are being created by that program *Archive Utility* that I've never heard of. Again, there's a clue in the filename – the `gz` in `.cpgz` indicates to me that this new file is compressed using [gzip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip). I am guessing that *Archive Utility* cannot read Olympus' proprietary binary file format either, so it does what it thinks you want it to do – create a new compressed copy of the file.

Comment: Archive Utility is the built-in unzipper my Mac tried to open it in.

Comment: @Stormblessed File extensions are used to indicate to a user and to a computer what the file type is and what application should be able to read that file. (The computer GUI usually displays a particular icon based on the file extension.) But there can be problems when one file extension is used by multiple file formats. Your _Archive Utility_ application seems to be associated with the `.bin` file extension, but `.bin` is used for many different actual file types, and there is no guarantee that _Archive Utility_ can read this `.bin` file from Olympus. Indeed, it seems it can't.

Comment: Why? Curiosity! More than good enough reason!